# shut down system via REST url

Tags: scripts, shutdown

How can I trigger a shutdown via REST url?
I call sth. like "http://192.168.1.20/command/shutdown" and the system shuts down. This should work from any other computer in the same subnet. How can I do this? I'd like to avoid running an apache server for this.

(pls. don't give any advice that this is not useful, dangerous or stupid)

Comment: I would look for a program listening on the http socket, which can trigger the shutdown event. The nc linux command is able to listen on ports. If you stick to http, then apache link could create a file on the server and server cron job could pick up the existence of the file and perform shutdown.

Comment: "pls. don't give any advice that this is not useful, dangerous or stupid" is a silly request - you're already doing something "dangerous or stupid", and "not useful" is on you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Ubuntu, if you have a version with systemd, then you can use it to listen on a port for you and run a service and script when there is an incoming request. For example, for testing, as an ordinary user create a Unit to listen on port 5000:

```
cat <<\! >~/.config/systemd/user/my.socket
[Unit]
Description=my socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=5000
Accept=true
!
```

Create a user service of the same prefix name ("my") to run `~/myscript`:

```
cat <<\! >~/.config/systemd/user/my@.service
[Unit]
Description=my service
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/meuh/myscript
StandardInput=socket
StandardOutput=socket
StandardError=syslog
!
```

Create the script to read/write stdin/stdout for the http protocol:

```
cat <<\! >/home/meuh/myscript
#!/bin/bash
printf 'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n'
printf 'Status: 200\r\n'
printf '\r\n'
matched=false
while read input
do [[ "$input" =~ ^$'\r'?$ ]] && break
   [[ "$input" =~ ^'GET /command/shutdown HTTP/' ]] && matched=true
done
if $matched
then echo "shutdown"
else echo "hello"
fi
exit 0
!
chmod +x myscript
```

Start the socket:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user start my.socket
```

Connect to it with curl, for example:

```
$ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000/command/stuff
> GET /command/stuff HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
Content-Type: text/plain
Status: 200

hello
```

or for shutdown:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/command/shutdown
Content-Type: text/plain
Status: 200

shutdown
```

Replace the echo shutdown by something appropriate, and the port number by 80 as usual for a web server. Obviously, you can do a non-user version of this, and also set the uid of the service unit to someone with rights for shutdown.

---

If you convert the above to system units, and place them in a standard place like `/etc/systemd/system/my.socket`,
then to enable it to start automatically at boot, you will want to make the socket wait until the network is ready; add to the .socket file `[Unit]` section:

```
After=network-online.target
```

and at the end

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

so that you can enable it with

```
systemctl --user enable my.socket
```

I'm not a systemd expert, so you might need to post new questions on this part, especially if you continue to use `--user` units, as they need more effort to start at boot (rather than the default, user login).

Comment: thank you, this looks good. but the program only listens once and then the service gets the error: "Failed to queue service startup job (Maybe the service file is missing or not a template unit?): Invalid argument"

Comment: This is because ExecStart must an absolute path name.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I was testing with totally different names and messed it up when copying them into the answer and editing them.

Comment: what do I have to do that the service is started automatically when the system is booted? (of course it is not necessary to have it running very early)

Comment: I've added what I think you need to do to the end of the answer, but I'm not able to test it, so you should post a new question if it isn't working for you.